# Swift RestKit CoreData - RKEntityMapping nil class for class name

Tags: core-data, swift, mapping, restkit

## Using RestKit and CoreData with Swift

RestKit offers functionality to map JSON directly into NSManagedObject instances.
You use the following code line to init a RKEntityMapping object:

```
var classMapping :RKEntityMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName:"className",inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore)
```

This causes the following error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot initialize an entity mapping for an entity with a nil managed object class: Got nil class for managed object class name 'className'. Maybe you forgot to add the class files to your target?'

The error occurs because of this line in RestKit API:

```
Class objectClass = NSClassFromString([entity managedObjectClassName]);
```

### Solution:

If your NSManagedObject class is written in Swift, you have to add the following code before your class declaration:

```
@objc(className)

class className {
...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Darn, I wasted a whole evening trying to figure out why I was getting this error.  One way I attempted to fix it was to replace the `representedClassName` with `projectName.className` instead of simply `className`.  That actually fixed this specific error, but later started throwing exceptions in RestKit mapping after data was returned by my Restful API.

Comment: I did file a RestKit issue, because generally the NSManagedObject subclasses are generated and should not be changed manually...  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2181